# Django remove user from all groups

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to remove a user from all the groups that is assigned to. I am using the standard auth app in Django.

So far I am able to delete one group at a time with:

```
user.groups.remove(group)
```

but this adds a lot of sql overhead. I understand that this is an many-to-many relation, but I am not able to find which model represents the many to many mapping and call the delete method from there.

I would like to execute the following query with the Django ORM:

```
delete from auth_user_group where user_id = 123
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know what is the SQL, but you can use the [`clear` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear):

```
user.groups.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help